# Ubuntu 22.04 - lock screen, cannot reenter the desktop

Tags: lock-screen

After booting Ubuntu 22.04, I enter my password and log into Ubuntu. So all fine so far. If I leave my notebook unattended for some time, my computer turns into suspension mode. Then when I try to end suspension mode by rotating my screen, and hit the power button shortly, I click the password field and reenter my password, but this does not pen my desktop account again. Then the only possibility  to reenter desktop is to force a reboot. Why can I not unlock my desktop account? The password was always entered correctly.

Strangely, I can enter my desktop account without problems after suspension mode sometimes, and sometimes in seemingly the same situation entering the password after suspension mode does not allow me to enter the desktop account, but I cannot determine what the reason is.

Comment: When you "restart the computer, i.e. ending suspension mode", do you Left click in the password field? Did you tap the Piwer button? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Sorry, to be slightly ambiguous in my description. What I mean by "restarting the computer", is the following: Previously I have not shut down the computer, so now rebooting would not be necessary, since I have just suspended it. Then, after a while, I open my laptop by rotating the screen up , then after hitting the keyboard or just  shortly the power button, the screen turns on again and I click the password field and enter the correct password, but without entering into my account.  I hope this clarifies my question. @waltinator Shall I edit my question to describe my problem better?

Comment: @waltinator I edited my question. I hope this satisfies better the standards for this forum.

Comment: @waltinator the problem disappeared, not sure exactly why, but in the last few days since I last communicated, on no occasion the problem reoccurred. Maybe a recent update I performed helped, not sure what it was.